# How to merge a function into another

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-signals

Sorry for asking a basic thing. new to Python and Django ,
I want to resend email if the OTP from PUT request is incorrect.
I have a function which send email with otp automatically on Register.
But if user PUT incorrect OTP I want to resend that email with new otp, So I want to merge `sent_email_otp` into `verifyEmail` function.
So how could I achieve that?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def send_email_otp(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            subject = "Your email needs to be verified to use site"
            message = f'Hi, Dear {instance.name} use this following OTP to Get verified your email : OTP({instance.otpForEmail})'

            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [instance.email]
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
            print(f"Email Sent to {instance.email}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Something Wrong at send_email_otp")


@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def verifyEmail(request, pk):

    user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=pk)

    data = request.data
    otp_to_verify = data['otpForEmail']

    if otp_to_verify == user.otpForEmail:
        user.isEmailVerified = True

        user.save()
        message = {'detail': 'Your email is now verified'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:

        message = {
            'detail': 'OTP is not valid and expired, Use New OTP which we have sent you on the email'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Edit:
If I simply call the send_email_otp() inside else statement of verifyEmail then this error comes :

```
TypeError: send_email_otp() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'sender', 'instance', and 'created'
```

Comment: Call `send_email_otp()` function in the `else` condition of `verifyEmail`?

Comment: Tried already , This error comes TypeError: send_email_otp() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'sender', 'instance', and 'created'

Answer (score 0):

You cant call the signal directly unless you provide it the expected input.

You will need to create another function for sending the otp. and call it in the post_save signal and in the view

```py
def send_otp(name, email, otpForEmail):
    subject = "Your email needs to be verified to use site"
    message = f'Hi, Dear {name} use this following OTP to Get verified your email : OTP({otpForEmail})'

    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    print(f"Email Sent to {email}")


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def send_email_otp_on_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            send_otp(instance.name, instance.email, instance.otpForMail)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Something Wrong at send_email_otp")


@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def verifyEmail(request, pk):

    user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=pk)

    data = request.data
    otp_to_verify = data['otpForEmail']

    if otp_to_verify == user.otpForEmail:
        user.isEmailVerified = True

        user.save()
        message = {'detail': 'Your email is now verified'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:

        message = {
            'detail': 'OTP is not valid and expired, Use New OTP which we have sent you on the email'}
        send_otp(user.name, user.email, user.otpForEmail)
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard for you to configure the same function to send_mail again to send OTP, as you said this sends the email when the user gets registered. So why not modify the verifyEmail itself.

First, you don't need a user instance here as the user is already authenticated and you already have the User Id.

So in the else statement of `verifyEmail`, you can send_email without calling `send_email_otp()` function.

Update the verifyEmail to.

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def verifyEmail(request, pk):

    user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=pk)

    data = request.data
    otp_to_verify = data['otpForEmail']

    if otp_to_verify == user.otpForEmail:
        user.isEmailVerified = True

        user.save()
        message = {'detail': 'Your email is now verified'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        subject = "Your email needs to be verified to use site "
        message = f'Hi, Dear {user.name} use this following OTP to Get verified your email : OTP({user.otpForEmail})'

        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [user.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
        print(f"Email Sent to {user.email}")
        message = {
            'detail': 'OTP is not valid and expired, Use New OTP which we have sent you on the email'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks! it is sending the otp as i want.